# she has got me twisted with her actions

Tags: grammar

''isn't it the only way to love?
I don't regret for giving more of myself to Pratheeksha.
Probably she needed it the most but not anymore'' he replied.
'she loved me with her words but she has got me twisted with her actions,' Abhinay added again

She ***has got me twisted*** , by Prabhu pothula.

what is the meaning of this structure?
She became me twisted?

Answer (score 1):

It simply means that the woman has acted in a way (most likely in an undesirable manner) that has caused the man to become "twisted". This is likely to have happened over a long period of time (perhaps months or years).

Twisted means

> 1. mentally or emotionally unsound or disturbed : SICK (Merriam-Webster)
>
>    - And you know there will be some strange and twisted bitter man who will listen to all our messages.
> 2. strange and slightly unpleasant or cruel (Cambridge)
>
>    - The experience had left her bitter and twisted.